# How to allow the space key and backspace key in VB.NET/ Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: vb.net

How do I allow the space key and backspace key in VB.NET/ Visual Studio 2008?

Sample code:

```
Private Sub txtname_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                             ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) _
                             Handles txtname.KeyPress

    If e.KeyChar < "A" Or e.KeyChar > "z" And e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True
        txtname.Clear()
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

For Backspace use the [`Asc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Function and test for the [Hex Value](http://www.asciitable.com/), in this case 8, for the Space you can just test for `" "`

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 OrElse e.KeyChar = " " OrElse e.KeyChar < "A" OrElse e.KeyChar > "z" Then
    e.Handled = True
    CType(sender, TextBox).Clear()
End If
```

If your question is how to check BackSpace and Space the above answer will work. To allow them along with your Text then do something like this

```
If Not ((Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 OrElse e.KeyChar = " ") OrElse (e.KeyChar >= "A" AndAlso e.KeyChar <= "z")) Then
    e.Handled = True
    CType(sender, TextBox).Clear()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Work at Visual Studio 2012:

```
Private Sub Username_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Username.KeyPress
     If Not (Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 32) Then
                e.Handled = True
     End If
End Sub
```